# A way in fiddler to replace a parameter before submiting the answer to the server

Tags: fiddler

I tried to write in the CustomRules.js in OnBeforeResponse method:

```
if(oSession.PathAndQuery.StartsWith("/feed/predata/1-1-"))
{
    oSession["PathAndQuery"] = oSession.PathAndQuery.Replace("false","1");
}
```

The full PathAndQuery looks like that

```
/feed/predata/1-1-false-2.dat
```

When i try to save the file I get an error sound without a messagebox to show me where the error is.

I also tried this code:

```
oSession.PathAndQuery = oSession.PathAndQuery.Replace("false","1");
```

What is the correct way to perform this action?

Thanks in advance,

Oz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to change the request, you need to put your code in the *OnBeforeRequest* method.

Also,

```
oSession["PathAndQuery"]
```

doesn't do anything you want it to. Use this instead:

```
oSession.PathAndQuery = oSession.PathAndQuery.Replace("false","1");
```